# Setting up clearcase view through nautilus file manager

Tags: command-line, nautilus

On my workplace, in order to access certain folder on the server, say `/x/y`, I need to set up a clearcase view using the `cleartool` command. (I don't have much idea about `clearcase` or `cleartool`). Only then can I browse through its files/directories. All this can be done using the command line.

I was wondering if I could do the same through a graphical file manager, like nautilus: it would make my job easier.

However, if I set up a view and then invoke nautilus from the commandline, it cannot browse through `/x/y` directory. Nautilus says that it could not find `/x/y`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You must be talking about [dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378), since snapshot views don't have to be set (they are file-based workspace, available on your hard drive).

Regarding dynaic view, "set up" a view can refer to:

- starting said view ([`cleartool startview aDynamicviewTag`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_startview.htm))
- setting the view to a special mount point ([`cleartool setview aDynamicViewTag`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setview.htm), [warning, it spawns a new shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252436/python-and-clearcase-setview/10252612#10252612))

In the first case, you need to make a **[Nautilus script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NautilusScriptsHowto)** (that you could integrate in a Nautilus menu) which will:

- list all the view (`cleartool lsview -s`)
- start the view (or views) selected

In the second case, you would need to make a script used in a contextual menu:

- taking as parameter only the directory selected in the file manager,
- checking that directory is directly under `/view` (all dynamic views are mounted under `/view`: `/view/aDynamicViewTag`)
- call `cleartool setcs aDynamicViewTag` on that view (you can only set one view at a time: its content will be under `/vobs/aVob/...`)